# string not outputting the data

Tags: c++, string, bit

I am reversing bits of an integer by first putting the bits in a string.
Why `cout` of `nu_string` is an empty string.

```
    uint32_t reverseBits(uint32_t n) {
    string nu_bits;
    for(int i=0; i<32;i++){
        nu_bits.push_back(n>>i)&1);
        cout<<nu_bits<<endl; //prints nothing
    }
    //cout<<stoi(nu_bits); Throwing an exception
    //terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
    //what():  stoi
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Please post a Minimal reproducible example which compiles and runs

Comment: You should be getting build errors on that `push_back` line you show.

Comment: As for your problem, there's no known encoding where `1 == '1'` and `0 == '0'`. You add non-printable "characters" to the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push_back` is for adding characters to a string, if the first character is 0 than the string is NUL-terminated and so will be empty.
You probably meant to do this: `nu_bits.push_back('0'+((n>>i)&1));`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

```
-----------------
Dec  |   CHAR VALUE
-----------------
0    |   NULL
1    |   SOH
...
```

Both of them are non printable characters. What you probably meant to add the the string was '0' and '1'. The values of which are 48 and 49 respectively.

So, change the `push_back()` to following

```
    nu_bits.push_back( ((n>>i) & 1) + '0' );
   //OR
    nu_bits.push_back( ((n>>i) & 1) + 48 );
```